# Do Yakuake, Tilda provide the same functionality?

Tags: linux, console

Is there any difference between those programs? Are they just ordinary consoles that always run and called by single keystroke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are definitely similar in top-down functionality, although there are some distinct differences.

- Yakuake runs as a component on KDE
- Tilda runs on Gnome
- Function keys are assigned differently
- Yakauke allows you to adjust width/tabs
- Tilda does not have as many options